# How to start an industrial revolution without capitalism

Tags: technology, technological-development, industrial-age, manufacturing

In my fantasy world, the countries eventually industrialize. However, some of it is not capitalistic, but rather mercantilist, and the governments are absolute monarchs. Fortunately, the feudal system has been abolished, so people are not tied to a lord and his/her land. How would an Industrial Revolution occur without capitalism, or at least for it go evolve without it? Things to mention:

- They have a successful agricultural revolution
- People are tinkering with mechanical systems
- Metallurgy is advanced and strong
- There are enough diverse resources to help the civilizations
- These kingdoms are based on 17th century European kingdoms, and one of them is based on the Ottoman Empire

Note: There are no socialist or communist states at this point in time, and this question is not about industry in non-capitalist societies, but how they would start the first one.

Comment: Isn't mercantilism something that's slapped on top of capitalism or feudalism? (basically a foreign policy not an economic system per-se, despite what Wikipedia states). How does the money/power distribution work for the common-people, what's their motivation to produce the goods to outperform neighbouring countries?

Comment: The biggest problem is that capitalism is often accredited with allowing people and rich business owners the freedom to create and innovate the way they did, which seems to be one of the leading factors of what caused the Industrial Revolution. If you want a revolution without capitalism, you need to find some alternative motivation for innovation and technological growth. Perhaps the government insists that it must be done.

Comment: *"Some of it is not capitalistic, but rather mercantilist":* This phrase has no meaning. It's llike saying that some wine is not red, but rather crimson-colored. The question should explain what unusual meanings it assigns to the words "capitalistic" and "mercantilist".

Comment: 'capitalism' is a very loaded word. Please. Please clarify which definition you are using. because depending on definition, the answer can range from trivial to impossible.

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question. Our own industrial revolution didn't occur "because of capitalism." Innovation requires an economy that can pay for it - and a lot of innovation came because of military expenditures. In fact, capitalism as you understand it is a derivation of economics first proposed by Adam Smith in the 18th century (a century after your target society, problem solved!). So, what is it about capitalism that's causing you grief? What's the real problem? (VTC:Needs Clarity until answered.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this qualifies for your answer, but what do you think of the [Meiji Restoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiji_Restoration)?

Comment: If we could figure that one out, there'd be a lot of happy leftists out there. Alas, it is impossible.

Answer (score 13):

**In the style of the Pharaohs.**

The people are not tied to the land.  They do not need to work for the local feudal lords.  In dissolving feudalism, the absolute ruler took control of all of that.  Now everyone works for the Pharaoh.

https://www.bbc.co.uk/history/ancient/egyptians/pyramid_builders_01.shtml

> At Giza the workforce was divided into crews of approximately 2,000
> and then sub-divided into named gangs of 1,000: graffiti show that the
> builders of the third Giza pyramid named themselves the 'Friends of
> Menkaure' and the 'Drunkards of Menkaure'. These gangs were divided
> into phyles of roughly 200. Finally the phyles were split into
> divisions of maybe 20 workers, who were allocated their own specific
> task and their own project leader. Thus 20,000 could be separated into
> efficient, easily monitored, units and a seemingly impossible project,
> the raising of a huge pyramid, became an achievable ambition.
>
> As bureaucracy responded to the challenges of pyramid building, the
> builders took full advantage of an efficient administration, which
> allowed them to summon workers, order supplies and allocate tasks

Instead of building a pyramid, your Pharaoh oversees industrial works.    The workforce must work for the Pharaoh and in return the workers and their families are supported by the Pharaoh with food produced by farmers who are also working for the Pharaoh.

There are some real positive aspects to this system, chief among which is that there is not an aristocracy to concentrate wealth.  No-one is going to be setting themselves up as a mini Pharaoh.   Instead wealth can be distributed more equitably.  Administrators are paid well and have a culture of honesty.  Consumer goods produced by the workers are exported but also sold to the workers because the workers have disposable income because they are not being exploited by some mini Pharaoh.

Work hard and earn your pay.  Fill your belly and raise your family.  Dress and worship as you choose.  Challenge the authority of the Pharaoh and be crushed.

ALL HAIL THE IMMORTAL PHARAOH!

Comment: *" No-one is going to be setting themselves up as a mini Pharaoh"* - the problem is that this will never work. A rival to the Pharaoh will convince the administrators, that if only they allowed him to depose the pharaoh, those administrators will get a larger share of power. So in order for this not to happen, the Pharaoh himself needs to give them more share of power, to keep them loyal.

Comment: @vsz A tyrannical despot or absolute monarch who centralises power to themself and cuts out the bureaucracy is a pretty common historical occurrence. The late Muammar Gaddafi did it consciously so that if anyone killed him it would be very hard to control Libya (and it worked, killing him resulted in chaos). Ivan the Terrible is another example. Sometimes it's even good for a country.

Comment: @vsz But administrators can't do anything about that themselves - they need an army. A key part of the feudal structure was that armies were loyal to their lord first and their king very much second, not least because their lord had the power of life and death over their families. An army that considers themselves loyal to the king first, and whose family income and safety come from the king, isn't going to have that risk. Not that they might not rebel as a group, sure, but the administrators have much less power over them.

Comment: @SeanOConnor : even in the case of the most absolute and central dictatorship, the dictator didn't rule alone. The number of people in the inner circle was small, but there was an inner circle. The purges are necessary to keep the inner circle small so that the rewards of the members of the inner circle can be kept high.

Comment: For sure. The point is that there were no credible alternative power centres under many Pharaohs. His desire was law, and he was an absolute monarch to a degree that Louis XIV or Richard II could only dream of.

Answer (score 9):

**Incentives Still Exist Without Capitalism**

For instance, the Industrial Revolution was great, but it couldn't have existed with the Age of Enlightenment paving the way with scientific advancements, and those were all made fine within the existing non-capitalistic structure.

Capitalism is a system by which to maximize individual profits, but industrialization doesn't require the profits of every individual to be maximize. Just *specific* individuals. The easiest way to start one would be to create a new class within the system, the class of inventors, and to make sure the Crown fully funds and supports industrialization. I would imagine it would function similar to the way of knights, people could apprentice under existing inventors and innovators, peasants might get rewarded by one for an exceptional invention, etc.

The important thing to remember is that as long as you place the incentives in the right area, you can induce your desired behaviors. Reward inventing and even if the rest of your society doesn't look like capitalism, than you'll still get the industrial revolution.

Comment: You don’t need a special class of inventors; all we needed was to stop the Church executing anyone who thought for themselves. It was only *one generation* from the Peace of Westphalia to the start of the Enlightenment.

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, capitalism is about private ownership of the means of production, to use the first line of the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalism) definition. Two or three important things happened during the industrial revolution:

- The most important means of production changed from being [real estate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_estate) (used to farming) to being factories (and the [working capital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_capital) to maintain them).
- The most important means of production were owned not by the traditional landholding classes (be they feudal nobles or yeoman farmers), but by a new class of investors. This process went hand in hand with the change of what was important.
- Rules for trading the most important means of production were significantly relaxed. (Again in part because the nature of the most important means changed. To this day, it many countries it is more complex to buy a garage than a car.)

So what you need is to get the first bullet point, without the others. Basically, the ownership and sale of factories should be about as complex and regulated as the ownership and sale of land.

- Assume that commercial and manufacturing activity requires a [royal charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_charter), and that those are personalized. They can be inherited, but not sold. Ownership of such a charter is more important than either a factory site or tools (or the money to buy them) in your setting. In a way, they become the means of production.
- Holders of such a charter might need to find 'silent partners' or 'investors' to provide capital, but the laws are biased towards the charter holders. Also, the "supply" of charters is managed so that there are always more investors than charter holders, giving them the upper hand in negotiations.
- Members of the royal household and high nobility find it much easier to get charters. Using them is socially accepted, they are not 'sullied' by such industrial endeavours.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you can't create a secret factory easily. Pre-industrial revolution the best use of land might have been farming (I've not checked, my gut says, yes). which requires acre and acres to be efficient and thus is hard to hide. A small factory (without a charter) would be quite easy to hide or disguise.

Answer (score 1):

The Soviet Russians managed this (at least in a follow-on sense) very much without capitalism. They might have done it poorly but they very much managed to take an agrarian country into a world power in just a couple generations.

Comment: However, they did have the industrial revolution before they came to power. Although most of the country was agrarian, the soviets had as their core a population which migrated to the cities and became factory workers, before the soviet revolution started.

Comment: You fail to explain how they did this in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Industrial Revolution never needed Capitalism; it needed the Enlightenment, which coincidentally also produced Capitalism.

Once enough some clever people begin to question the traditional (artisanal) ways of doing things, they will eventually invent steam engines and mass production, and then combine those to create factories. The rest will mostly take care of itself, though the details may vary a bit depending on your exact economic and political system.

Comment: They might make a steam engine, but its hard to see how you get factories and mass production without capitalism.

Comment: @SeanOConnor Why? There is nothing stopping a noble, a trade guild, a church, or any other wealthy party from building a factory. The “need” for a separate class of capitalists has always been a scam.

Comment: @SeanOConnor FYI, feudal China had the basics of mass production in ~210 BCE (see: Terracotta Army).

Comment: Sure, it's not impossible. But the pool of potential factory owners is much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: There are limited number of kinds of good to be produced in this world, and all the ways producing them are suddenly given to people without more reasons. Actually it's assumed true in many fantasy worlds, such as games that the only assumed mass produced things are standardized weapons. You just observe how normal people do their job and how much they get in a capitalism world, implement exactly the same things in your world, and just say they are all designed by a monarch. The "revolution" could be a monarch suddenly got the list of technologies, decided to invest on them, and ordered everyone to work on it. As long as the structures above the normal people level hardly change, for the reason that nobody is able to find new demand, the people controlling it or working behind it don't matter much, because it doesn't require wisdom power to maintain. Actually I don't think it's any unnatural if you just handwave this, for the reason that a reader generally only remember a limited number of kinds of good anyway, and won't just discover new demands themselves. Even "diverse resources" in a story are very limited compared to real life.